# Cordova camera not launching

Tags: android, cordova

I tried many ways and referred many questions here but still my camera is not launching.Help me in this.I checked manifest and config xml files.there is no error in that.Can any one give me working example for cordova camera.

```
<script>

var pictureSource;   
var destinationType; 
document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);

function onDeviceReady() {
    pictureSource=navigator.camera.PictureSourceType;
    destinationType=navigator.camera.DestinationType;
}


function onPhotoDataSuccess(imageData) {

  var smallImage = document.getElementById('smallImage');

  smallImage.style.display = 'block';

  smallImage.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
}
function onPhotoURISuccess(imageURI) {

  var largeImage = document.getElementById('largeImage');

  largeImage.style.display = 'block';

  largeImage.src = imageURI;
}


function capturePhoto() {
    alert("varun");
   navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, { quality: 50,
    destinationType: destinationType.DATA_URL,
    sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA });
}

function onFail(message) {
  alert('Failed because: ' + message);
}

</script>
```

Comment: You should use sourceType:navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA 
or use  
sourceType: pictureSource.CAMERA 
or you can leave this because by default it takes camera